# Is there a way to update caller scope variables from php closure

Tags: php, php-5.6, php-closures

`use` keyword with php closure is a pretty clear way to extend the scope of handpicked variable to closure.

Is there any way if we need to update the value of some variable in caller function scope from closure?

```
$total_strength = 0;
$all_cores->each(function($core) use ($total_strength) {
    $total_strength += $code->strength;
});

print('Cumulative cores' strength is: ' . $total_strength);
```

Here I always get 0. How to fix that?

Comment: [`Pass it by reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) -> `use (` **&** `$total_strength)`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Please reply in proper way I will mark it accepted. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply pass the argument [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), Like this:

```
use (&$total_strength)
   //^ See here
```